# Cocoa: Create, and close, one window from another

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, appdelegate

I am looking for the simplest example which shows one window opening another window and then closing it.

The place where I seem to get stuck is with the NIBs and how the outlets should be wired. I can easily get the window created; closing it presents a challenge.

Any advice much appreciated!

I'm attaching my code below. I think what I am trying to do is simple, yet it doesn't work. Thanks to Francis I can now get the window to open and close but once I try to open it again the application crashes (`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`). I'm sure this is due to my poor understanding of the NIB relationship to classes. In most languages I would just need to instantiate a new instance of a window and then close it.

I have 2 windows in `MainMenu.xib`. (I'd prefer to have the window in a separate NIB but that appears to create other problems!) The AppDelegate has 2 outlets, to window (original) and otherWindow (2nd window created).

The first window has 2 buttons: "*Open Window*" and "*Close Window*" with connections to the 2 methods in the code.

**Code:**

*MyTestAppDelegate.h*

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MyTestAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSWindow *window;
    NSWindow *otherWindow;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *otherWindow;

- (IBAction)openOtherWindow:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)closeOtherWindow:(id)sender;

@end
```

*MyTestAppDelegate.c*

```
#import "MyTestAppDelegate.h"

@implementation MyTestAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize otherWindow;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
}

- (IBAction)openOtherWindow:(id)sender
{
    [otherWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:sender];
}

- (IBAction)closeOtherWindow:(id)sender
{
    [otherWindow close];
}
@end
```

Comment: Very important detail: This is for a Mac application, not an iOS application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, in your NIB you create the various windows, add your buttons, textfields, etc. Then you add a custom object that acts as a "controller" that sends and receives messages to and from the windows and various controls. In a simple project you can use the automatically-created AppDelegate object to control your windows, for bigger projects you want a separate object to handle the logic, which can be an instance of NSObject or NSWindowController, depending on your needs.

Windows can be set up as "Visible at launch" which opens them when your app launches. You can also open them manually by creating IBOutlet references in the header files and connecting them in the NIB. To show windows you send them a `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` message. To close them you send them a `close` method.

To respond to window opening/closing you assign your controller object as the windows' "delegate", which means it will recieve messages from the windows, which are listed in the documentation under the NSWindowDelegate protocol. So if you wanted to open a window in response to another window closing, you would listen for the `windowWillClose:` message and tell the other window to open, and vice-versa.

This is pretty basic stuff so I recommend you read the Hillegass book, or browse some of the various [tutorials](http://cocoadevcentral.com/) [available](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?CocoaTutorials) [online](http://www.cocoatraces.com/).

EDIT:

You're application is crashing because you have your otherWindow set to "Release when closed" Since you are in a memory-managing environment, and nothing is retaining the window, the next time you try to open it it has already been freed. The solution is to uncheck "Release When Closed" in the NIB file. Notice you can also connect your button actions to `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` and `performClose:` methods of the other window itself, directly in the NIB.

Comment: Thanks Francis. I agree it is basic but I've still not gotten a full understanding of how NIB's work. When I tried using 2 NIBs I found that calling the close from the controller inside the NIB would close the window properly, but using a reference externally (e.g. from the original window) would see a null window. I edited my question with precise code. I've searched many tutorial sites and cannot find the very basic example I am trying to create.

Comment: Thanks so much Francis! Exactly what I needed. Still trying to get the hang of the NIB files.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project by using the "UINavigationController" template in XCode 4.1 or the "Master-Detail Application" template in XCode 4.2 and have a look at how the stuff is working there.

If you are not interested in learning by reviewing the XCode template have a look at following tutorial: http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uinavigationcontroller-tutorial/

Comment: Mention of "windows" indicates the poster is not dealing with iOS.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. Perhaps I should have been clearer that what I am looking for is on a Mac application, not an iOS application.

Comment: Having said that - I will still look at the examples in case there is code that is similar to what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Rick The cocoa tag implies Cocoa on Mac OS X. For iOS, the name used by Apple is Cocoa Touch; on Stack Overflow, the corresponding tag is cocoa-touch.